# Spark Streaming: Persist not working

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have 2 streams. Stream1 receives data occasonally, usually only in first batch. Stream2 constantly receives data. I want to left outer join Stream2 to all the data Stream1 has received. I tried the following, but it's failing to account previous batches received in Stream1.

```
val s1 = ssc.receiverStream(new CustomReceiver(1005))
val s1p = s1.map...
val s2 = ssc.receiverStream(new CustomReceiver(1006)).persist()
val s2p = s2.map....persist()
val joined = s2p.leftOuterJoin(s1p)
```

In the logs, I see messages about removing Stream2's RDDs from persistence list.

Comment: I believe you are misinterpreting the use of persisting? have you looked at windowing?

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan Are you referring to sliding window? I don't think it would solve my problem of joining with all previously received RDDs of Stream1.

Comment: Yes, and it should! Why wouldn't it!?

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan I may not be understanding windowing correctly- but isn't the window size fixed? At the time I perform join, I may lose RDDs received to the left (earlier) of the window.

Comment: windows operations can be used to join DStreams.. http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html